# Transferring locally uniformly convex norm by bounded linear operator from one Banach space to another

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm trying to find a simple proof this theorem

> Let $Y$ be a locally uniformly convex Banach space and $X$ be a Banach space and let $T$ be a bunded linear operator from $X$ into $Y$ such that for every bounded sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $X$ with $\|Tx_n-Tx\|\to 0$ we have that $$x\in \overline {span (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}}^{\|.\|}$$  (in particular, whenever $x\in \overline {conv (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}}^{\|.\|}$ , or weak-$\lim x_n=x$). Then $X$ is locally uniformly convex renormable.

I think we need to use an equivalent norm as follow
$$|x|=\|x\|+\|Tx\| \ \ \  \text{for all }x\in X$$ Is it correct? 
Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Transfer techniques is presented in Section 2 of Chapter II and in Section 2 of Chapter VII of the book Deville-Godefroy-Zizler, Smoothness and renormings in Banach spaces. Possibly some of this techniques can be adjusted to cases you are interested in.